# Quick question on the basis of subset of polynomals

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U = {p $\in$ $P_4(F)$: $p(2) = p(5) = p(6)$} Find a basis of U.

So the way I did this problem was by writing out $p(2) = p(5)$ and $p(5) = p(6)$, then I made a system of equations and solved for the ratio. The basis I got out of this method included two polynomials that were both of degree $x^4$. I figure I must have made a mistake.

Long story short, do I need to make a system of equations involving $p(2) = p(5)$, $p(5) = p(6)$, and $p(2) = p(6)$, or can I just continue to use the method I used before?

Comment: Is $P_4(F)$ the collection of polynomials over the field $F$ of degree at most four?

Comment: at most 4, including 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subject to the uncertainty of what $P_4$ is, and what $F$ is, here’s just one way of looking at it:

You know the dimension of $P_4$ is five, if as @Michael Albanese guesses, it’s all polynomials of degree at most four. You should know that each time you specify a value of a polynomial, you put one more linear condition on the coefficients. So your space has codimension two, (there are two equals signs in your conditions), so the dimension of your space is $3$. Of course your subset is a vector subspace, since the sum of two good functions is good, and a multiple of a good function is good. Anyhow, it’s easy to find three entirely different functions satisfying your conditions. How about $1$, $(x-2)(x-5)(x-6)$, and $x(x-2)(x-5)(x-6)$? The last, being of degree four, is clearly not in the span of the other two, you have a basis.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand I'm doing this right, since I've been using a different technique, if I had the condition $p(6) = 0$, then my basis would have degree four and I could say such a basis is {$(x-6), x(x-6),x^2(x-6), x^3(x-6)$}. How would I know to exclude the one in this case??

Comment: Because for the function $p(x)=1$ identically, $p(6)\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $p$ is a polynomial such that $p(2) = p(5) = p(6) = 0$ then $$p(x) = (x-2)(x-5)(x-6)q(x)$$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ by the Factor Theorem. If $p \in P_4(F)$, what are the possible degrees of $q$? What if $p(2) = p(5) = p(6) = k$?

Comment: I never understood how to do these types of problems that way. If you could write it out I would appreciate, but if not, I'm just saying that what I did was write out a system of equations:

Comment: p(2) - p(5) = 0, p(5) - p(6) = 0 and then solve for the ratios. I'm just asking if I also need to have p(2) = p(6) when solving for the coefficients?

Comment: "I never understood how to do these types of problems that way." I strongly suggest you try to learn. What part do you not understand? As for your second comment, if $p(2) - p(5) = 0$ and $p(5) - p(6) = 0$, then $p(2) = p(5)$ and $p(5) = p(6)$, so $p(2) = p(6)$ (so you don't need to add this as a separate condition).

Comment: This is just a shaky topic for me, but this example is actually making a lot more sense thank you!

Comment: I like this answer better than my own more complete one.